# How to resolve Exception LocalMemcacheService not found?

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, jakarta-ee, jetty

I have a J2EE Web Appliation...

Built On: Eclipse JUNO (Google app hosting)
OS - Window 7 32_bit
JDK 1.7.0

I am very new to google app development.
I ran and terminated my application many times due to modifications in servlet classes.

But now I am facing a problem to run the app. I did not understand by this error but got is that it is related to  memcache which gae use to store frequently required data.

After googling found that It has limited space. And can erase if full from admin console.

But not got how to do it or is it neessary for the exception..

On running it showing exception...

```
    Aug 15, 2013 11:27:54 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineWebXmlReader readAppEngineWebXml
    INFO: Successfully processed C:\Users\Atul Dwivedi\git\CareerYantra\war\WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml
    Aug 15, 2013 11:27:54 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AbstractConfigXmlReader readConfigXml
    INFO: Successfully processed C:\Users\Atul Dwivedi\git\CareerYantra\war\WEB-INF/web.xml
    Aug 15, 2013 11:27:54 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.SystemPropertiesManager setSystemProperties
    INFO: Overwriting system property key 'java.util.logging.config.file', value 'C:\eclipse\plugins\com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.8.1.1\appengine-java-sdk-1.8.1.1\config\sdk\logging.properties' with value 'WEB-INF/logging.properties' from 'C:\Users\Atul Dwivedi\git\CareerYantra\war\WEB-INF\appengine-web.xml'
    Aug 15, 2013 11:27:55 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger info
    INFO: Logging to JettyLogger(null) via com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger
    Exception in thread "main" java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: com.google.appengine.tools.development.LocalRpcService: Provider com.google.appengine.api.memcache.dev.LocalMemcacheService not found
at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:231)
at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$300(ServiceLoader.java:181)
at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:365)
at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:445)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocalImpl.startServices(ApiProxyLocalImpl.java:595)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocalImpl.access$700(ApiProxyLocalImpl.java:46)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocalImpl$2.run(ApiProxyLocalImpl.java:584)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocalImpl$2.run(ApiProxyLocalImpl.java:581)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocalImpl.getService(ApiProxyLocalImpl.java:580)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractContainerService.installLoggingServiceHandler(AbstractContainerService.java:277)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractContainerService.startup(AbstractContainerService.java:302)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AutomaticServerInstanceHolder.startUp(AutomaticServerInstanceHolder.java:26)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractServer.startup(AbstractServer.java:80)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.Servers.startup(Servers.java:82)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.start(DevAppServerImpl.java:237)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain$StartAction.apply(DevAppServerMain.java:339)
at com.google.appengine.tools.util.Parser$ParseResult.applyArgs(Parser.java:48)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.<init>(DevAppServerMain.java:274)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.main(DevAppServerMain.java:250)
```

Please help how to overcome from this ? And also suggest some useful resources to read more of read.

Comment: please include the exception you are getting.  We can't help you if we don't know what the problem is

Comment: And the code that caused the exception might be nice too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"project which is built".  It is not 100% clear what language you are using (you are hinting at java, but eclipse can be used to write in other languages), so I will assume the following:

- You are using eclipse to program in java
- Both machines have the same version of java OR the destination machine has a higher version of java than the source machine.
- the compiler compiled it using 32-bit java

If all of these conditions are true, then yes, it will work.  Some problems that can arise if one or more are not met:

If java is not the language you are using, then all of this is irrelevant, and you will need to specify what language you are using.

If the destination machine has an older version of java than what the compiler built the program in, then it will not be able to run.  This is because java is not forwards compatible (this is normal behavior).

**This** is the important one: IF the compiler built the code into a 64-bit program then **NO, the program will not run**.  This is because it is impossible for your 32-bit system to have 64-bit java installed.  64-bit machines can run 32-bit code (usually), but not the other way around. Aleroot is correct when he says that the platform and architecture are independent of the host machine, but you must still have a 64-bit JRE to run 64-bit java code, and that JRE cannot run on a 32-bit CPU.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if it is a Java project.
Java is platform and architecture independent, and the program should run without any problem.

Comment: But on running this project it is showing exception... Unsupported major.minor version 51.0, java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError. Project is also built on JDK 1.7 same as I have.